# Python Selenium: ElementNotInteractableException or TimeOutException on a drop-down menu

Tags: python, selenium, drop-down-menu

When i try to reach a drop-dpwn menu with the code:
`select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name('select1'))`
`select.select_by_value('$0-$500M')`

I get a ElementNotInteractableException on the select by value line.

I tried to solve the error with this code:
`select = Select(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.NAME, 'select1'))))`
`select.select_by_value('$0-$500M')`

And i get a TimeoutException on the first line.

Does anyone know how to solve the problem?

Comment: Please post the url to investigate

Comment: Can we have some relevant HTML or link to page ? also please share entire error stack trace.